# Calculating Standard Error of Standard Deviation

Tags: self-study, sampling, references, inference, random-effects-model

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694812/standard-error-of-variance-component-from-the-output-of-lmer/31704646#31704646) , I think first I need to be theoretically sound .

In my theory class , I learnt that inverse of information matrix is the variance-covariance matrix of estimates . To find the variance-covariance matrix , we follow the following step :

(1) First we need to write down the log-likelihood expression  which is done by `dd.ML <- lme4:::devfun2(model,useSc=TRUE,signames=FALSE)` in the post . Isn't it ?

(2) then we need to create information matrix which is done by  `hh1 <- hessian(dd.ML,pars)` in the post .

(3) And the last step is to take the inverse of the information matrix which can be done by `solve(hh1)` . But I don't understand why is there 2 multiplied with `solve(hh1)` in the post `vv2 <- 2*solve(hh1)`

Also , why do I need to double `sqrt(diag(vv2))` to get the  standard errors of the variances , i.e., `2*sqrt(diag(vv2))` ? Why is not `diag(solve(hh1))` all to calculate the  standard errors of the variances ?

Comment: Note the function in step 1 is for deviance rather than log-likelihood (see e.g. [What is Deviance? (specifically in CART/rpart)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6581/17230)). So there's a factor of two that's to come out at some point.