# Shouldn't -2*loglike of an lm object = deviance of that lm object in R?

Tags: r, regression, lm, likelihood

I want to make sure my R code below is accurate. Because generally `-2*logLik(lm_object)` should equal `deviance(lm_object)`.

But in my R code below, these two numbers don't match. Do I have a bug I'm missing?

```
set.seed(2)
n = 300
x <- rnorm(n)
e <- rnorm(n, 0, 3)
B0 = .5 ; B1 = 2

y <- B0 + B1*x + e
m <- lm(y~x)

-2*logLik(m) #   1500.681 !!

deviance(m)  #  2612.792  !!
```

Comment: The `deviance` formula is `sum(weighted.residuals(object)^2, na.rm = TRUE)` and you can check the function `getAnywhere('logLik.lm')`.  It should be a different one

Comment: @akrun, thanks! But see the equality that I mentioned applies here: `library(lme4);hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv');

f1 <- lmer(math ~ ses + (1 | sch.id), data = hsb);

-2*logLik(f1);
deviance(f1)`

Comment: arguably the deviance calculation in `lme4` is **wrong**.  I had thought that deviance==-2L for a continuous probability density, but that's not true ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this CrossValidated answer points out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315788/deviance-in-simple-linear-regression), the deviance (which is the difference between `-2*log(L)` for the model and `-2*log(L)` for the *saturated model*, multiplied by the dispersion) for the linear model is equal to the sum of squared residuals (weighted, if  necessary).

Here is the computational analogue of the algebra done in the linked answer:

```
deviance(m) ## 2612.792
sum(residuals(m)^2) ## 2612.792
nll2_m <- -2*sum(dnorm(y, predict(m), sd = sigma(m), log=TRUE))  ## 1500.688
nll2_s <- -2*sum(dnorm(y, y, sd=sigma(m), log=TRUE))  ## 1202.688
(nll2_m - nll2_s)*sigma(m)^2  ## 2612.792
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try testing with the original statistical definition of log likelihood:

```
#Data
set.seed(2)
n = 300
x <- rnorm(n)
e <- rnorm(n, 0, 3)
B0 = .5 ; B1 = 2
#Model
y <- B0 + B1*x + e
m <- lm(y~x)
```

What you did is correct:

```
#Code 1
-2*logLik(m)
```

Output:

```
'log Lik.' 1500.681 (df=3)
```

And the statistical perspective:

```
#Code 2 below statistical definition
sigma <- summary(m)$sigma
-2* sum(log(dnorm(x = y, mean = predict(m), sd = sigma)))
```

Output:

```
[1] 1500.688
```

Comment: But shouldn't `-2*logLik(m)` equal `deviance(m)`?

Comment: It depends of you compare the full saturated model and the estimated model.

Comment: But Duck, it applies in here: `library(lme4);hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv');  f1 <- lmer(math ~ ses + (1 | sch.id), data = hsb);  -2*logLik(f1); deviance(f1)`

Comment: It is a generalized linear model with different degrees of freedom. That might be the reason why values are equal. In the case of a linear model the results can differ!