# Deviance and MSE confusion (Boosting, Random Forests, Bagging)

Tags: boosting, mse, deviance

I am following Hastie & Tibshiriani ISLR

In Chapter 8 they introduce Bagging, Random Forests and Boosting.

To compare each model they plot a curve of Test Error VS number of trees.

Various goodness of fit measures are mentioned: **RSE/MSE** (for regression), **Gini index**, **cross-entropy** and **classification error rate** (for classification).

They never explicitly reference Deviance - I looked here for a definition [What is Deviance? (specifically in CART/rpart)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/what-is-deviance-specifically-in-cart-rpart)

While helpful, it does not really tell me how it relates to the measures mentioned above.
If I understand correctly: deviance is a measure of distance between two models.

- Deviance in regression equals RSS (**why?**). Particularly the distance between the candidate model and a perfect fit model, so the lower the better.
- And for classification, the sum of the Gini index or cross entropy error for all trees compared to a perfect fitted model gives the deviance of predicted vs observed (**how?**).

Can someone explain how all these relate to using "MSE" in the book, both in a regression and classification context? Why the ISLR book does not use **deviance**?